# MalformedPolicyDocument error while creating an IAM Policy

Tags: json, shell, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a managed policy by `AWS CLI`:

```
POLICY='
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":
  [{
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Action":
    [
      "cloudformation:*"
    ],
    "Resource":"*"
  },
  {
    "Effect":"Deny",
    "Action":
    [
      "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
      "cloudformation:DeleteStack"
    ],
    "Resource": "'${arn}'"
  }]
}'

# Create policy if not already created
[ $(aws iam list-policies | grep -ce CloudFormation-policy-${StackName}) -eq 0 ] && (aws iam create-policy --policy-name CloudFormation-policy-${StackName} --policy-document "'${POLICY}'")
```

When I run the script I get this error:

```
An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreatePolicy operation: Syntax errors in policy.
```

I can't figure out where the error is.
Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to run this from CLI? Did you valid this in AWS Console? My guess is this issue is due to single quote vs double quotes.

Comment: Yes it's from CLI. 
When I do `echo "'${POLICY}'"` I get the json in simple quotes

Comment: Which OS your CLI is running on? Windows or Linux or Mac?

Comment: Linux ubuntu 16

Comment: Before you spend anytime on debugging, if you have access to AWS console, I would suggest try to create a policy with this and make sure it passed validation there, that confirms json is correct. Once JSON validation done, for command line json parameters I would suggest using this approach (params in file) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-param.html#cli-using-param-file

Comment: the policy is valid. I think  it does not take the Arn parameter. I will try the approach in the provided link. thank you

Comment: I successfully created the policy. Could you provide an answer with the details you have said in your comments please? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each operating systems has its own way of treating single quote vs double quote escaping and as per [AWS CLI documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-param.html):

> When passing in large blocks of data, you might find it easier to save
>   the JSON to a file and reference it from the command line. JSON data
>   in a file is easier to read, edit, and share with others.

[Quoting Strings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-param.html#quoting-strings) approach might not be best choice while passing Json data, instead use [Loading parameters from file approach](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-param.html#cli-using-param-file).